# Are two empty lists guaranteed to be 'eq?' in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Is `(eq? '() '())` guaranteed to be true in Racket?

If not mistaken, two empty lists are guaranteed to be `eq?` in R7RS, but I want to know if Racket also provides such a guarantee.

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=eq%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eq~3f%29%29), but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's specified explicitly, but the example at https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null%29%29 shows that it's guaranteed to be `eq?`.

Comment: The very first Scheme(r) was an interprenter under Interlisp and borrowed primitives from there. `'()` was the hosts `nil` which also is [a constant](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_nil.htm). It has always been `eq?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The behaviour of `eq?` more or less follows `eq?` from Scheme.

The documentation on `eq?` could be clearer though. The documentation on lists has the following to say:

> A list is recursively defined: it is either the constant null, or it is a pair whose second value is a list.

So the empty list is a constant - which means it is unique.